# Calculating average from numbers in .txt file using Python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

```
def main():

    total = 0.0
    length = 0.0
    average = 0.0

    try:
        #Get the name of a file
        filename = input('Enter a file name: ')

        #Open the file
        infile = open(filename, 'r')

        #Read the file's contents
        contents = infile.read()

        #Display the file's contents
        print(contents)

        #Read values from file and compute average
        for line in infile:
            amount = float(line)
            total += amount
            length = length + 1

        average = total / length

        #Close the file
        infile.close()

        #Print the amount of numbers in file and average
        print('There were ', length, ' numbers in the file.' )
        print(format(average, ',.2f'))

    except IOError:
        print('An error occurred trying to read the file.')

    except ValueError:
        print('Non-numeric data found in the file')

    except:
        print('An error has occurred')


main()
```

This is how the numbers in my .txt file appear:

```
78
65
99
88
100
96
76
```

I keep getting "An error has occurred" when I try to run. After I comment that out I get a divisibility error. I tried to just print out the total and length to see if they were actually computing but each is 0.0 so apparently I have some problems in getting them to accumulate correctly.

Comment: If you want to figure out what went wrong, first try **not** catching the exception, so that you can see the traceback.

Answer (score 2):

`infile.read()` consumes the file. Consider writing each line as you come across it instead.

Answer (score 2):

`infile.read()` will take the entire file, not individual portions.  If you want individual portions, you'll have to split them up (by space) and get rid of the whitespace (that being `\n`).

Obligatory one-liner:

```
contents = infile.read().strip().split()
```

You would then wish to iterate over the contents of `contents`, as that would be the only thing worth iterating over.  `infile` is already exhausted, and subsequent calls to `read()` will generate an empty string.

```
for num in contents:
    amount += float(num)
    # more code here

 average = total / len(contents) # you can use the builtin len() method to get the length of contents instead of counting yourself
```

Comment: The code already iterates over the lines in the file properly after; it just needs to avoid consuming the file in the first place.

Comment: This code has a bug, it should be amount += float(num)

Answer (score 0):

I modified you code to see if I could make it work and still look as much like yours as possible. This is what I came up with:

```
def main():

total = 0.0
length = 0.0
average = 0.0

    try:
        #Get the name of a file
        filename = raw_input('Enter a file name: ')

        #Open the file
        infile = open(filename, 'r')  

        #Read values from file and compute average
        for line in infile:
            print line.rstrip("\n")
            amount = float(line.rstrip("\n"))
            total += amount
            length = length + 1


        average = total / length

        #Close the file
        infile.close()

        #Print the amount of numbers in file and average
        print 'There were', length, 'numbers in the file.' 
        print format(average, ',.2f')

    except IOError:
        print 'An error occurred trying to read the file.' 

    except ValueError:
        print 'Non-numeric data found in the file'

    except:
        print('An error has occurred')

main()
```