# I Would Like to Take the Average of All the Numbers in a Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, valueerror, readlines

```
def getFile():

    while True:
        try:
            fileName = input('Input a File Name: ')

            file = open(fileName, 'r')
            return file

        except IOError:
            print('Error, File Name Does Not Exist')

def readFile(file):

    sumTotal = 0
    count = 1

    line = file.readline()
    num = float(line)

    while line != ' ':
        sumTotal += num
        line = file.readline()
        num = float(line)
        count += 1
    avg = sumTotal / count
    return avg

def main():

    file = getFile()
    avg = readFile(file)

    print(avg)

    file.close()

main()
```

[image]

I would like to get each number from the file, picture above, and take the average of all of the. However I continue to get the error, ValueError: could not convert string to float:. I have a line though that shows that I convert the string from the file into a float.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Is that the entire txt file? Maybe there's a line with a space in it?

Comment: Maybe try changing line != ' ' to line != ''

Comment: It's not, the entire file, but I made a fresh file with only a few numbers and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Add a print(line) above the float conversion. That should let you see what the string was and to decide how to handle it

Comment: It looks like it's just take the first line as a string, but just stops and shows the error after that.

Comment: [Examples of what you're trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866515/calculating-average-from-numbers-in-txt-file-using-python).  From the 3rd answer your problem could be you have need to strip the line before the float conversion due to a trailing "\n".  This would explain why you get the error on the first line.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

Try my method, replace **def readFile(file)** with my code.
Code below opens and reads testNum.txt using **with** as context manager, and subsequently converts the string to int in a list. Finally computing the average.

```
with open("M:/Desktop/testNum.txt", 'r') as tf:
    list_ = [int(i) for i in tf.read().split()]
    print(sum(list_)/len(list_)) #returns average of all numbers in text file
```

Comment: If one of the values in the file is not a number, you will still get a ValueError (though arguably this is more elegant than the extremely verbose code the OP provides).

Comment: Yup, true. This is with assumption that all values are numbers as specified by TS.